# read raw data from disk and convert

Tags: hard-disk, text-formatting, data, hexdump

please help to find a way to convert the data as follows:
I read from disk using dd utility

> dd if=/dev/sdb  skip=8388608 count=560 iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes |hexdump  -C

and I am getting

> 000001a0  00 00 00 00 cf 4c 79 ce  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.....Ly.........|

but I would like to get :

> 000001a0  ce794ccf00000000 0000000000000000  |.....Ly.........|

I do not have to use hexdump, any other tool can also do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify some more: You want each set of 8 bytes shown in reverse order but the normal character display stay untouched?

Comment: Exactly. I got the answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reversed order of hex bytes is due to little-endian processing of single bytes.

hexdump does not seem to allow for 64-bit values, but od (octal dump) does. Replace the call to hexdump with:

```
od -t x8z
```

which outputs 64-bit hex long-words, and ASCII. The ASCII is bracketed by >...< which should be easy to skip.

Comment: Great answer, will do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`hexdump`'s output is fully customisable even if the syntax may seem a bit obscure at first:

```
$ seq 10 | hexdump -C
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 33 0a 34 0a  35 0a 36 0a 37 0a 38 0a  |1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.|
00000010  39 0a 31 30 0a                                    |9.10.|
00000015
$ seq 10 | hexdump -e '"%08.8_ax " 2/8 " %016x"' -e '"  |" 16 "%_p" "|\n"' -e '"%08.8_Ax\n"'
00000000  0a340a330a320a31 0a380a370a360a35  |1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.|
00000010  0000000a30310a39                   |9.10.|
00000015
```

The byte order (little endian above) for those 64 bit integers depends on your system's computer architecture / C compiler.

Note the 0 padding to satisfy the missing bytes for the last number above.

Note that rather than using `dd`'s `skip` and `count`, you can use hexdump's `-s` and `-n`.